# How can I fix my quicksort implementation?

Tags: scheme, quicksort

Here's my attempt to implement quicksort:

```
(define (sublist ls start stop middle)
 (cond ( (null? ls) ls)
     ( (< middle start) (sublist (cdr ls) start stop (+ middle 1)))
     ( (> middle stop) '() )
     (else
        (cons (car ls) (sublist (cdr ls) start stop (+ middle 1))))))

(define (split5 ls)                                      
  (let ((len (length ls)))
   (cond ((= len 0) (list ls ls) )
         ((= len 1) (list ls '() ))
         (else 
          (list (sublist ls 1 (/ len 2) 1)
                (sublist ls (+(/ len 2)1) len 1))))))

;this divides the sorted list into two sublists 
(define (dividelist rel? ls)
 (split5 (order rel? ls)))


(define (quicksort rel? ls)
 (if (null? (cdr ls)) ls
  (let ((pivot (list-ref (sort rel? ls) (round (/ (length (sort rel? ls)) 2))))
        (left (car (dividelist rel? ls)))
        (right (cdr (dividelist rel? ls))))
        (join left pivot right))))
```

I know this implementation is very inefficient but I can't think of a way to do it. Anyway, it doesn't really work.

```
When I input this:
(quicksort < '(9 3 -5 8 -7 2 9))
It gives me this:
(-7 -5 2 8 (8 9 9))
It should give me this:
(-7 -5 2 3 8 9 9)
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT

```
(define (join ls1 goo ls2)
  (if (null? ls1) (cons goo ls2)
      (if (null? ls2) (cons goo ls1)
          (cons (car ls1) (join (cdr ls1) goo ls2)))))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(right (cdr (dividelist rel? ls))))` at the end of quicksort be using `cadr` instead of `cdr` ?

Comment: Where's the `order` procedure? I hope it isn't a sort procedure :P . Also, where's the `join` procedure?

Comment: ...yeah order uses the sort procedure. Is that bad?

Comment: @taylor18 Certainly. Using `sort` to implement `quicksort` doesn't make sense. The whole idea of implementing a sorting procedure from scratch is to perform the sort by hand, it's pointless to use another sorting procedure in it. Quicksort doesn't depend on the existence of another procedure for sorting, and the way you're selecting the pivot is plain wrong. Just pick the first element. And use the `join` procedure shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `order` procedure is the same as the `sort` procedure used a few lines below in your code (wait, you're using a sorting procedure to implement a sorting procedure?!) and that `join` is some kind of `append`, I can conclude that the list creation problem is in your implementation of `join`. Change it to this to fix it:

```
(define (join left pivot right)
  (append* left (list pivot) right))
```

Now the procedure will return a *list*, as it should:

```
(quicksort < '(9 3 -5 8 -7 2 9))
=> '(-7 -5 2 8 8 9 9)
```

Ooops, where did the number `3` go? There's a bug in your code, you'll have to find it! Hint: the code for calculating the pivot is terribly wrong.

**EDIT**

Here's a correct, hassle-free implementation of QuickSort. Notice that in a simple implementation like this it's enough to pick the first element as the pivot:

```
(define (quicksort cmp lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (let ((x  (car lst))
            (xs (cdr lst)))
        (append (quicksort cmp (filter (lambda (e) (cmp e x)) xs))
                (list x)
                (quicksort cmp (filter (lambda (e) (not (cmp e x))) xs))))))
```

Or slightly fancier and shorter, using Racket's higher-order procedures:

```
(define (quicksort cmp lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (let ((x  (first lst))
            (xs (rest  lst)))
        (append (quicksort cmp (filter-not (curry cmp x) xs))
                (cons x (quicksort cmp (filter (curry cmp x) xs)))))))
```

Yet another possibility, using `partition` to obtain both partitions (the elements before the pivot and the elements after the pivot) in a single step - it's more efficient:

```
(define (quicksort cmp lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (let-values (((greater-than less-equal)
                    (partition (curry cmp (first lst)) (rest lst))))
        (append (quicksort cmp less-equal)
                (cons (first lst) (quicksort cmp greater-than))))))
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(quicksort < '(9 3 -5 8 -7 2 9))
=> '(-7 -5 2 3 8 9 9)
```